# Como administrar processamento do Jquery ou Javascript puro?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Recentemente tive o seguinte problema numa aplicação híbrida: Um comando não era executado, porque outro processo era mais veloz, e redirecionava a página. Sem saber como funciona o gerenciamento de processos do javascript (linguagem que originalmente não era para se comportar como uma linguagem de programação tradicional) usei as funções setIntervel e setTimeOut para improvisar uma "fila" de carregamento, administrada em milissegundos. Isso foi a solução para aquele caso específico, mas está muito longe de ser o ideal segundo tudo que já vi de desenvolvimento.
Eu nunca ouvi falar de programar trats em javascript, ou gerenciamento de memória (salvo o cuidado com escopo de variáveis var/let), e para contextualizar essa minha ignorância, não me considero um desenvolvedor javascript, por isso a dúvida. Por coincidência, li em um material sobre jquery, que o script Jquery é executado quando toda a página é carregada, o que me fez pensar que talvez tenha alternativa para essa questão. Caso a opção seja desenvolvedor diretamente para um servidor em nodejs, acho inviável, porque aplico o javascript em "n" contextos fora de servidor nodejs. Note que a dúvida não se trata de exclusivamente performance, mais manipular processos, aonde a execução 1 necessariamente aconteça antes da execução 2, sem emporcalhar o código com milhares de "if"s ou "dowhile".

```js
function primeiro(){
    //Esse código acontece em 500 milissegundos 
}

function segundo(){
    //Esse código acontece em 200 milissegundos 
}

primeiro();
segundo();
```

Comment: *" que o script Jquery é executado quando toda a página é carregada"* isso é simplesmente o evento `DOMContentLoaded`
Sugiro dar uma olhada nos eventos disponíveis para `window`  e `document`.

Comment: Sérgio Lima: de que maneira a resposta aceite responde à tua pergunta? Não vejo a relação entre as duas...

Comment: Também não entendi a relação da pergunta com a resposta aceita. Eu entendi que vc quer um jeito de garantir que `segundo()` só será executado depois que `primeiro()` terminar, independente do tempo que demorem - e nesse caso, eu sugiro dar uma olhada na API de [*promises*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises). [`performance.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) só está medindo o tempo que algo demorou para executar, ou seja, as funções já terão executado e vc não garantiu ordem nenhuma...

Comment: @Sergio Ele queria sabe qual é o valor da perfomance,ele disse que tava certo e disse que resolveu. Eu estou confuso...

Comment: Só achei estranho relação da pergunta com minha resposta. Eu até fiz uma resposta,mas ele disse que tava errado(sobre perfomance).

Comment: Vou criar uma versão de resposta diferente, para deixar claro em que ponto o seu problema resolve, e os tradicionais temporizadores (setInterval e setTimeOut) não resolvem.

Comment: Sérgio, seria interessante também [edit] a pergunta para deixar mais claro qual é o problema, assim a resposta passa a fazer mais sentido (pois da forma que está, não parecem ter nenhuma relação aparente).

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Use esse método que calcular a velocidade do seu código:

```js
function doSomething() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    window.document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = i;
  }
}
var t0 = performance.now();
doSomething();
var t1 = performance.now();
console.log("Call to doSomething took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.");
```

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id='resultado'></p>
</body>
</html>
```